# Is it possible to write new clang-tidy modernize rules?

Tags: c++, qt, clang-tidy

In particular, I'm using Qt; our codebase is still littered with old `foreach` macros, like `foreach (T foo, bar) { ... }`. I'd like to turn that to `for (T foo : bar) { ... }`. Is there a way to write a clang-tidy rule to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. Clang-tidy is open source so nothing stops you from modifying the code or writing your own checks.

The [modernize-loop-convert](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-loop-convert.html) check does something very similar to your use case so it's possibly a good start. ([source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/master/clang-tidy/modernize/LoopConvertCheck.cpp))

Clang-tidy even has official [documentation on writing new checks](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/Contributing.html).

Comment: Thank you. I searched a bunch but didn't find it. I had hoped (and perhaps expected?) that it could be done with config files – something like regexps on the AST – so that assumption may have lead me in the wrong direction when searching.